# Nginx - Not distributing traffic to all upstream servers

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

We have an existing issue on our nginx.. As you can see on the attached screenshot, the requests are not distributed evenly on the 12 servers and only 4 are getting most of the traffic

Hoping you can provide inputs on how to address this.

Thank you[image]

Comment: have you noticed the servers with the fewest requests have 10 to 20 times longer response times? Please show in the question how you have configured the load balancing.